# SpringBoot - gradle plugins for JDK1.6

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot, java-6

I need to bring up a spring boot application with jdk1.6 as the target websphere is on 1.6. Gradle version iam using currenty is 2.10.

The plugins/dependencies  I need for my project are :

1. com.netflix.nebula:gradle-dependency-lock-plugin
2. se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker
3. org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin

But whatever versions I tried, I am facing the " Unsupported major.minor version 51.0" error. Can someone please help me with what exact versions might help/work with jdk1.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to finding Java 6-compatible plugins, you could build with Java 7 or 8 and produce Java 6-compatible byte code by setting `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` to `1.6` in your `build.gradle`:

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.6
targetCompatibility = 1.6
```

Comment: Thanks Andy. By setting the above properties and commenting sonarqube and checkstyle ( which i missed mentioning ), the application came up in 1.6. Currently working on enabling sonarqube and checkstyle in the application.

Comment: The sonarqube and checkstyle went fine. For sonarqube, made the revision/version to 1.2 and it went fine.

Comment: Thanks Andy. It finally worked with all plugins in place.